# Transforming extremely skewed data for regression analysis

Tags: python, pandas, normal-distribution

I have a Pandas Series from a housing data-set (size of the series = 48,2491), named "exempt_land". The first 10 entries of this series are:

```
0         0.0
2     17227.0
3         0.0
7         0.0
10        0.0
14     7334.0
15        0.0
16        0.0
18        0.0
19     8238.0
Name: exempt_land, dtype: float64
```

As the data size is quite large, I did not perform **dummy_variable** transformation.

Now, my goal is to carry out regression analysis. Hence, I would like to transform this data to appear **Normal**.

The original data has a **Skewness** of **344.58** and **Kurtosis** = **168317.32**. To better understand the original data, I am also including the **Distribution plot** and **Probability plot** of the original data.

[Distribution Plot BEFORE transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ8Sm.png)

[Probability Plot BEFORE transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljrlW.png)

After performing **Log** transformation, I get the **Skewness** of **5.21** and **Kurtosis** = **25.96**. The transformed **Distribution** and **Probability** plots now look as follows:

[Distribution Plot AFTER **np.log10(exempt_land + 1)** transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1rk8.png)

[Probability Plot AFTER **np.log10(exempt_land + 1)** transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k63x.png)

I also performed various other transformations ("power", "exp", "box-cox", "reciprocal") and I got similar bad results (in reciprocal transformation case, the results were quite worse).

So my question is, how can I 'tame' this data to behave nicely when doing regression analysis. Furthermore, upon transformation, the **skew** of **5.21** is still quite high, will this create any problem?
What other transformations can I perform to make the data look more **Normal**?

I hope my questions are clear here. Any help from the community is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: We really need to see the 'distribution before' plot, it's impossible to read, if you plot on a linear x-axis; please pick a much narrowed x-axis (or use lo or log-log x-axis). Also, please post images here directly, not links to imgur (which are ephemeral and likely to break/decay)

Comment: *"I also performed various other transformations... and I got similar bad results "* but `log1p()` was what you wanted, per your graphs

Answer (score 0):

With all the zeros, you need to use a non-normal distribution. Some variety of Tobit might make sense here. (You can't transform discrete data and get less discrete data.)